# MS SQL coonditional check null value

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to select records from tbl_A based on A_Class field from tbl_B as below

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_A
WHERE A_Class IN (SELECT A_Class FROM tbl_B)
```

However, the A_Class might contains NULL value

I need to add in another condition

If A_Class contains NULL value, then

```
WHERE A_Class IN (SELECT A_Class FROM tbl_B) OR A_Class IS NULL
```

If no null value, the condition to check NULL need to be ignore/remove

So my question is, is it possible to make it become a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code if there aren't blank values (I mean '') in A_Class:

```
SELECT * FROM #tbl_A
WHERE exists
     (SELECT * FROM #tbl_B
     where isnull(#tbl_A.A_Class,'')=isnull(#tbl_B.A_Class,''))
```

If blank values are present, you can use even this: `isnull(#tbl_A.A_Class,'NULL')=isnull(#tbl_B.A_Class,'NULL')` with typed phrase 'NULL'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show all the records without null values:
`SELECT a.* FROM tbl_A a INNER JOIN tbl_B b ON a.A_Class = b.A_Class WHERE a.A_Class IS NOT NULL;`

If you want to show all the records without null values from tbl_A and all of them that are in tbl_B:
`SELECT a.* FROM tbl_A a LEFT JOIN tbl_B b ON a.A_Class = b.A_Class WHERE a.A_Class IS NOT NULL;`

If you want to show all the records without null values from tbl_B and all of them that are in tbl_A:
`SELECT a.* FROM tbl_A a RIGHT JOIN tbl_B b ON a.A_Class = b.A_Class WHERE b.A_Class IS NOT NULL;`